# Надо обновлять listview при каждом нажатии checkbox, слушатель находится в custom simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, checkbox, listview

Хочу обновлять listview в активити каждый раз при нажатии checkbox, но при вызове метода updateTodo() из checkbox listener приложение не работает.

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.getListView().setDividerHeight(2);
    dbHelper = new TodoDatabase(this);

    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextNewTask);

    RowId = null;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    RowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null
            : (Long) savedInstanceState
            .getSerializable(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_ID);
    if (extras != null) {
        RowId = extras.getLong(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_ID);
    }

    startService(new Intent(this, TimeService.class));
}
.........
.........
    public void updateTodo(){
    fillData();
}


private void fillData() {
    cursor = dbHelper.getAllTodosListView();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    }

    String[] from = new String[] {TodoDatabase.COLUMN_ACHIEVED, TodoDatabase.COLUMN_SUMMARY,
                                    TodoDatabase.COLUMN_TIMESECONDS};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.checkBoxLabel, R.id.textViewLabel };

    // Теперь создадим адаптер массива и установим его для отображения наших
    // данных
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to, 0);

    notes.changeCursor(cursor);
    notes.notifyDataSetChanged();

    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

SimpleCursorAdapter

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private CheckBox mCheckBox;
private long xId;


public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    final TodoDatabase mDbHelper = new TodoDatabase(context);

    final TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewLabel);
    mCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxLabel);
xId =Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor
.getColumnIndex(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_ID)));

  textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_SUMMARY)));
    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_TIMESECONDS)) != null) {
        if (cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_TIMESECONDS)) > 0) {
            if (cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_TIMESECONDS)) >
                    System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            } else if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_ACHIEVED)) != 1){
                textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            }
        }
    }

    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TodoDatabase.COLUMN_ACHIEVED)) == 1) {
        mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        final Long mRowId = xId;

        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Long mXRowId = mRowId;
                if (mCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                    TodoDatabase mDbHelper = new TodoDatabase(context);
                    mDbHelper.updateTodoAchieved(mXRowId, "1");

                    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                    ma.updateTodo(); // Ошибка

                } else if (!mCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                    TodoDatabase mDbHelper = new TodoDatabase(context);
                    mDbHelper.updateTodoAchieved(mXRowId, "0");

                    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                    ma.updateTodo(); // Ошибка

                }
            }
        });

    } else {
        mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
        final Long mRowId = xId;

        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            Long mXRowId = mRowId;
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (mCheckBox.isChecked()){

                    TodoDatabase mDbHelper = new TodoDatabase(context);
                    mDbHelper.updateTodoAchieved(mXRowId, "1");

                    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                    ma.updateTodo(); // Ошибка

                } else if (!mCheckBox.isChecked()){

                    TodoDatabase mDbHelper = new TodoDatabase(context);
                    mDbHelper.updateTodoAchieved(mXRowId, "0");

                    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                    ma.updateTodo(); // Ошибка

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Если мой ответ, ниже, вам подошел то отметите (примите) его как правильный.

Comment: Так и не смог разобраться к сожалению. Как только разберусь с вашим вариантом, обязательно отмечу результат.

Comment: мне подошел метод notifydatasetchanged() либо можно использовать INTENT.

Comment: В общем да, как я и сказал, есть много способов. Вы спросили и за чего у вас происходит падение/ошибка, а не лучший способ или разные возможные способы для обновления списка.

Answer (score 1):

Проблем в вашем коде много. Конкретно по вашему вопросу вам не надо создавать activity по новой, она уже существует, ошибка у вас и за этого `new MainActivity()`. Варианты есть разные, на пример, можно передать интерфейс с колбэком типа `onUpdateTodo` через конструктор а вашей MainActivity имплементировать этот интерфейс, а в конструктуре `MySimpleCursorAdapter` передавать `this`:

```
new MySimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to, 0, this);
```

Сохранить этот листенер как класс мембер (поле) и его и вызывать при нажатие на чекбокс `mListener.onUpdateTodo()`